# Is there a reason why every meson and baryon has an integer electric charge?

Tags: charge, standard-model, quarks, mesons, baryons

Is there a reason why every meson and baryon has an integer electric charge?

For example, why is there no meson existing of two up quarks, giving a charge of $\frac43$?

Comment: That duplicate doesn't have a particularly great answer, unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of the experimental observations that led to the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. The model has symmetries ( [SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)  ) that build up the representations and these allow only for integer multiples charges, i.e. are consistent with observations.

> For example, why is there no meson existing of two up quarks, giving a charge of 4/3?

You might say because there is no such a [representation  in the standard model](https://books.google.gr/books?id=BwistUlpZ7cC&pg=PA1067&lpg=PA1067&dq=standard%20model%20and%20fractional%20charge%20mesons&source=bl&ots=7-pme-4HiW&sig=t8YqaY_DI2-qH4xGxVQ1Sxaab2I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD_4K92_LMAhUpKsAKHQHkBKoQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=standard%20model%20and%20fractional%20charge%20mesons&f=false), but in truth it is because we have never observed such a case. Had we observed it, we would have found a different standard model.